# JSDom 11.12.0 - how to mock localStorage?

Tags: javascript, testing, jsdom

Since the latest release of JSDom, I'm not able to mock `localStorage` anymore.

I've tried the following methods:

1. `Object.defineProperty(window, 'localStorage', {value: LocalStorageMock})`
2. `window.localStorage = LocalStorageMock;`
3. `jest.spyOn(window.localStorage, 'setItem')`

Any of those methods not worked for me, I get always the original `localStorage`.

Answer (score 8):

`setItemSpy = jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem');` works for me.

Saw this fix here: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6858#issuecomment-413677180

Answer (score 3):

I actually ran into this same issue when updating Jest, not sure if that's what happened to you but I found this fix here: 
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6766

From OlivierB-OB:

> As a temporary workaround you can install jsdom "11.11.0" (exact) as a dev-dependency in your package. jest-environment-jsdom should then use this version instead of the lastest "11.12.0" causing the behavior.
>   Cheers!

After that I mocked localstorage in test setup and spying was back to normal.

And an implementation of localstorage mock: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2098 
lacks removeItem though, so you might need to add it.

Comment: The linked issue is not relevant, cause localStorage requires now a url, using jest, u can configure a url via `testUrl` jest property.

Comment: it's a bit buried in the comments but users are complaining that they cannot mock or spy on local storage post js-dom's 11.12.0 release. There's not a separate issue for that complaint at this point though, sorry if that wasn't a helpful link.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[dom-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dom-storage)** package available via npm:

```
const Storage = require('dom-storage');
global.localStorage = new Storage(null, { strict: true });
global.sessionStorage = new Storage(null, { strict: true });
```

We use the latest release of `jsdom` for our unit tests and the above method has worked great.

Comment: I don't see any assignment of the lib on `window.localStorage`, I am missing something?

Comment: @felixmosh The idea is that you would take my simple sample and modify it to fit your particular implementation. Just replace `global` with `window`.

Comment: the assignment that you made is not working, jsDom prevents the that assignment, check if you are really on the latest jsDom.

Comment: @felixmosh Does your JS code actually refer to `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` using `window.localStorage` and `window.sessionStorage`? That's not necessary. You can just drop the `window.` and use the implied global or use any manner of dependency injection techniques to include `localStorage` and `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 1):

I've create a function that mocks `localStorage`. It implements only two methods `getItem` and `setItem`. You can easily add other methods if needed.

```
export const localStorageImpl = {
    register: () => {
        let storage = (window as any).customLocalStorage;

        if(storage) {
            return {
                storage,
                methods: (window as any).customLocalStorageMethods
            }
        }

        storage = (window as any).customLocalStorage = {} as any;

        const setItem = jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'setItem');
        setItem.mockImplementation((key, value) => {
            storage[key] = value;
        });

        const getItem = jest.spyOn(Storage.prototype, 'getItem');
        getItem.mockImplementation((key) => {
            return storage[key];
        });

        const methods = (window as any).customLocalStorageMethods = {
            setItem,
            getItem
        };

        return {
            storage,
            methods
        }
    },
    unregister: () => {
        const methods = (window as any).customLocalStorageMethods;
        if(methods){
            const { setItem, getItem } = methods as { setItem: jest.SpyInstance<void, [key: string, value: string]>, getItem: jest.SpyInstance<string, [key: string]> };
            setItem.mockReset();
            getItem.mockReset();
        }
        delete (window as any).customLocalStorageMethods;
        delete (window as any).customLocalStorage;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
it('should mock localStorage', () => {        
    const { methods } = localStorageImpl.register(); // mock localStorage
    
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Root />);
    fireEvent.click(getByTestId('column-size'));        
    expect(methods.setItem).toBeCalledTimes(1);

    localStorageImpl.unregister();
});
```