# ReferenceError: Storage is not defined

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am a newbie on React and am trying to learn from web resources. I found MERN full stack login code on the web. When I try to compile using `npm start`, it has no issues, however when I try to compile using `npm test` it gives error 'ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined'

I tried to declare any variable of `localStorage` but also get a also similar error. It seems that I need to put the value somewhere but why is it giving an error on `npm test` only

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class Landing extends Component {

  logOut(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    localStorage.removeItem('usertoken')
    this.props.history.push(`/`)
  }

  render() {

    const loginRegLink = (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/login" className="nav-link">
            Login
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/register" className="nav-link">
            Register
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )

    const userLink = (
      <ul className="navbar-nav">
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/profile" className="nav-link">
            User
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="nav-item">
          <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)} className="nav-link">
            Logout
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    )

    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark rounded">
        <button
          className="navbar-toggler"
          type="button"
          data-toggle="collapse"
          data-target="#navbarsExample10"
          aria-controls="navbarsExample10"
          aria-expanded="false"
          aria-label="Toggle navigation"
        >
          <span className="navbar-toggler-icon" />
        </button>

        <div
          className="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center"
          id="navbarsExample10"
        >
          <ul className="navbar-nav">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <Link to="/" className="nav-link">
                Home
              </Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          {localStorage.usertoken ? userLink : loginRegLink}
        </div>
      </nav>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Landing)
```

Comment: this error is at line ` {localStorage.usertoken ? userLink : loginRegLink}`  If you mean userToken from locastorage of browser then try like this: `localStorage.getItem('usertoken')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569521/jsdom-11-12-0-how-to-mock-localstorage

Comment: @Revansiddh yes, i know it is error on that line but how to fix that issue, i already tried localStorage.getItem('usertoken'), but issues still remain

Comment: @Wenfeng its seems like code is correct. Here it is working https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-flower-0cdc2

Answer (score 1):

This is because localStorage doesn't work in test environment(jsdom).
You can look at [this](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1137)

Comment: Oh really? It seems to work in ours with no issues.